# save stderr with _popen to a variable in C on Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, windows-10

When I use something like

```c
char result[1000] = "";
char psBuffer[1000];
FILE* pPipe = _popen(command, "rt");
while(fgets(psBuffer, 1000, pPipe) != NULL)
{
    strcat(result, psBuffer);
}
printf(result);
```

Either when `command = "echo 123"` or `command = "ErrorCommand"` `result` only gets the value of the stdout, it never gets the stderr. At first it looks like it does since you get the error printed on your CMD but if you'll save the output and print it or save it to a file you'll see that it only contains the stdout.

Is there a way to make `result` also include the stderr?

Comment: Make your command redirect standard error to standard output. (I have no idea how to do this with Windows cmd language, assuming that's what's used to run the command by `_popen()`).

Comment: @Shawn After some digging around I don't think that there's a way to do it beside saving the stderr and stdout into a file and reading it which I prefer not to use.